# How to access the last indicator values

Tags: pivot, pine-script, indicator, trend

I've got an indicator which shows pivot points:

```
//@version=4
study("Trend", overlay=false)
leftBars  = input(3)
rightBars = input(3)

ph = pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
pl = pivotlow(low, leftBars, rightBars)
```

How can I check if the last ph was higher than the ph before? (I'd like to check for an uptrend or downtrend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code (including your original, as you see):

```
//@version=4
study("Trend", overlay=false)
leftBars  = input(3)
rightBars = input(3)

ph = pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
pl = pivotlow(low, leftBars, rightBars)

//INIT VARIABLES
var int ph_uptrend_flag = 0
var float ph_valid = 0
var float ph_valid_old = 1e99 // use any very high non meaningful number here for initialization only

ph_non_na = nz(ph,0) // stores 0's instead of na's for non-pivot-pointed bars

// re-calculate uptrend flag every time a new pivot comes in, otherwise keep last known value for uptrend flag
if ph_non_na != 0
    ph_valid := ph_non_na
    ph_uptrend_flag := ph_valid > ph_valid_old ? 1 : 0
    ph_valid_old := ph_valid
else
    ph_valid := ph_valid
    ph_valid_old := ph_valid_old

//plot uptrend flag and mark background accordingly
plot(ph_uptrend_flag,title="ph uptrend indication",linewidth=4,color=color.white)

//plot(ph,title="ph value",color=color.lime,style=8) //plot ph values (better used with overlay=true)
```

Comment: Ohh... thank you!! I didn' expect it to be so complex.... do I have to write all that for the pl also? I want to determine downtrends, too...

Comment: For the pl, you can replicate exactly the same, but you have to create new variables with prefix "pl_" where you read "ph_" in the answer above, and replace the comparison operator ">" by "<" for the PL check.

It becomes a bit complex because pivothigh() and pivotlow() functions result in 'na' values where there is no pivot, and we have to keep a memory placeholder for last valid pivot in order to make the comparison.

As usual in programming, maybe there is a simpler way - I prioritized speed over optimum code, though, to give you an answer ASAP :)

Comment: PS: I have made it for ph only because the original question reads "How can I check if the last ph was higher than the ph before?", and we're supposed to only answer the very question here, not inferred/implicit questions :)
My bad, I could have been less specific here