# Storing Pivots as a variables? Pine Script

Tags: variables, pine-script

Is there any way to store let's say 5 latest pivots as variables?
There is a simple built-in indicator call Pivot H/L which finds pivots and places plot shapes near them. Is there a way to store them instead of plotting the plot shapes?

Comment: Please refer to: [Example of storing pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736834/how-to-access-the-last-indicator-values/59743167#59743167)

Comment: @Glauco_Esturilio Thank you! I'm looking for something different. I want to store latest 5 -10 pivots as: piv1 = //code piv2 = //code piv3 = //code etc. is it possible?

Comment: Please see below. It's based somehow in the logic on the link, that is, we have to split the na's generated by the pivot functions when there is no pivot detected

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. It's ugly code, but you can. Here, I show you as an example to do it for the current and last 2 pivot highs. You can extend as much as you want creating more variables in analogy to what is here.
If you're interested in the pivot lows, also just replicate everything to the low pivots.
The way it is shown here, you'll find:

- `ph0`: the last found high pivot
- `ph1`: the penultimate last found high pivot
- `ph2`: the last found high pivot before `ph1`

This way, we keep (about) the same way we reference past elements of Series variables in Pine-script. Here the code:

```
//@version=4
study("Trend", overlay=false)

//INPUT VARIABLES
leftBars  = input(3)
rightBars = input(3)

//INIT VARIABLES
var float ph_valid = 0
var float ph0 = 0
var float ph1 = 0
var float ph2 = 0

ph = pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
ph_non_na = nz(ph,0) // stores 0's instead of na's for non-pivot-pointed bars

// Assigns non-na values to pre-instantiated variables
if ph_non_na != 0
    ph2 := ph1
    ph1 := ph0
    ph0 := ph_non_na
else
    ph2 := ph2
    ph1 := ph1
    ph0 := ph0

plot(ph0)
plot(ph1)
plot(ph2)
```